# What's the easiest way to convert a .jpg image with white background into .png with alpha channel?

Tags: png, jpg, imagemagick

example `.jpg`:

[image]

Ideal `.png` result:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Command line is quicker. Install [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).

One file:

```
convert -transparent white whatever.jpg whatever.png
```

More files:

Put together a bash script file:

```
for img in *.jpg; do
    filename=${img%.*}
convert -transparent white "$filename.jpg" "$filename.png"
done
```

Run it and then you will be done. Note that the above will add transparency to everything that is white 'FFFFFF' including any pixels of that colour inside your image. "topLeftPixel" can be used instead of "white" for autodecting background colour.

If the white pixels in image problem is a problem then you can do Photoshop batch. Layer mask is better than 'delete'-clearing the white pixels as you do not actually alter the RGB layers.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Imagemagick, but if that only converts pure #FFFFFF pixels, won't it leave ugly JPEG artifacts?  For instance, converting all white pixels to black in the reference JPG results in http://i.stack.imgur.com/CvvDy.png

Comment: You can add fuzzy in there if you want - there is an option in the ImageMagick manual. Sometimes some artwork is 'mounted' on white and you might be using against a white page background so 'fuzzy' may not matter.

Answer (score 3):

If you use GIMP, I can suggest this tutorial: [Perfect masking using a highpass guide](http://www.gimpusers.com/tutorials/highpass-masking). 
I had very good results with complex images by following it.

Comment: These tutorials can also be useful http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Changing_Background_Color_1/ http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Changing_Background_Color_2/

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the software you have available to you.

*If you have Photoshop*, for an image that clean you can do it very quickly:

1. Open the file.
2. Double-click the Background layer to convert it to a normal layer.
3. Use `Magic Wand (w)` (low Tolerance and Contiguous and Anti-alias checked) to select the white background.
4. Press Delete key to clear the selection.
5. Save as a PNG or Save-for-web as PNG.

If you get a white halo around your image, try using menu `Select` ⇒ `Modify` ⇒ `Expand` (with 1-2px setting) after step 3.

Comment: I think you can do better with a layer mask.

Comment: @Theodore If just resaving as a PNG, what is the benefit of preserving the underlying RGB info with alpha channel instead of just clearing pixels?

Comment: It is about using the rgb layers for the image and the alpha channel for transparency. If you delete pixels you do not get as good an edge as if you use a layer mask. Maybe that is just the way I hit the delete key. Give it a go, I promise you will get better results. That select-modify-expand is also verging on the morally wrong, you'll never get 'fine hair detail' doing it like that, but you will with layer mask.

Comment: @Theodore - There is no reason you can't have as fine of a line using "clear selection" as you can with a mask.  "Clear Selection" only removes pixel data for fully-transparent pixels.  For anti-aliased pixels it stores RGB data with alpha and you can still have a clean edge. [In this comparison](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mRd4G.png), I do not believe there is a substantial difference between the masked & cleared images.  As for recommending "Select-Modify-Expand", the question asked for "easiest way".  Easiest rarely equals best.

Comment: You can always delete a layer mask and apply it if you really want the empty pixel look with no extra layer/channel. You can also blur it and all kinds of things to get the exact results needed. If you have just deleted the pixels, albeit 'feathered' as per your technique you have lost the ability to re-work an edge later on.

Comment: @Theodore How do you retrieve RGB data from transparent pixels in a PNG in Photoshop?

Comment: If you look behind the back of the monitor you can see them. They can also fall out the bottom and go all over the desk. Happens all the time. Anyway... It is about using a non-destructive workflow. For internet projects you can have a complex action - removing white space borders, applying a mask, resizing and applying a 'sharpen' filter to get some of the resize blur back is a typical batch task. This can go badly wrong for some images or the complete set needs adjusting. Having a non-destructive 'hide' instead of a destructive 'delete' helps with any adjustments even if saved out to PNG.

Comment: @Theodore  If only it were that simple!  I have a black hole behind my monitor.  ;)  I'm not trying to be difficult, I'm trying to learn.  I thought when you mask a layer in PS and then save it as PNG, the excess RGB info got discarded.  I've even tried saving a few test images with layer masks but can't figure out how to resurrect the RGB info.  I understand the purpose of the non-destructive workflow, but this seems moot once the file is saved as PNG.

Comment: Far from moot - some habits are good and you don't want to get stuck with the wrong techniques even if there are lots of ways to 'skin a cat'. Tidy edges to images is something I learned with 'blue-screen' television production - creating a 'matte' on moving images even if they were wearing blue, had fine hair and stepped out of the lighting. I am a stickler for those principles and cannot 'just chop stuff out'. An adjustable matte is what works for me, but different strokes. Using Imagemagick and not even looking at stuff opens new creative opportunities too, particularly with websites.

Comment: @Theodore  Good points.  Thanks for bearing with me...

Comment: @Farray, there's a best practice in Photoshop known as "non-destructive editing." The fundamental is: never damage or change original pixels. That translates to specifics such as using masks rather than deleting things, using Smart Objects wherever possible, and a host of other details in the editing workflow. In this particular case, it might not be a big deal, since the original jpeg will be intact at the end of the edit, but it's better to get into good habits and stick with them. You never know when you might suddenly need them!

Comment: Along similar lines, try to avoid the Magic Wand or Magic Eraser (which does the selection and erasing in one shot) tools. The MW selects on an "all or nothing" basis, and even with anti-aliasing selections are only occasionally satisfactory. Color Range allows semi-transparency, and is much more controllable. Creating an alpha channel from one or more of the RGB channels gives very fine control over the selection. Either of those will, in almost every case, give you a better mask than the MW, and will never be worse.

Comment: @Alan Thanks for the pointers.  I don't disagree with your suggestions, but this was a very specific answer for a very specific question - "what is the *easiest* way" for the given example.  My answer, while not preferred on a technical level, is very easy (though not as easy as an Imagemagick script!) and effective for the provided scenario.  I hesitate to tell any user "avoid X tool", because each tool has their time & place.  In this scenario, I see little point to preserving fully nondestructive workflow since there is essentially only 1 transformation from source to product.

Comment: @Farrray You're quite correct in this particular instance (although I'd argue that the Magic Eraser is even easier than the Wand), mostly because the image in question is very dark, making for an easy clean edge. That's why I voted it up. Experience tells me this is an unusual case, though. It's very dark, and it looks like it had already been extracted from its original background, probably with the pen tool. Different colors (a white tee is the obvious example) wouldn't give such good results, so it's a special case where the MW happens to work.

Comment: @Alan - Good point about white shirt on white bg and agree that the image looked pre-cut.  (and also agree that ME would be even easier than MW in this scenario, I just forgot about that tool)

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completion i had to add one more method (if you using photoshop). As your image is not complex you can use the magic wand, or select color. But best method for separating a complex foreground from a relatively less complex background is Channel masking.

Here is a good tutorial which might be helpful for future visitors:
http://graphics.tutremix.com/tutorials/photo-effect/how-to-make-a-lightning-man-photomanipulation-in-photoshop-day-1/